# Accessing multiple element of list using loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a lists

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

I want to iterate to access 1, 4, 7, 10, then 2, 5, 8, 11, and then 3, 6, 9, 12. How to make this iteration?

Comment: kindly post how the output should look ... ```list(zip(*A))``` ?

Comment: yess, 
1, 4, 7, 10 (\n)

2, 5, 8, 11 (\n)

3, 6, 9, 12 (\n)

Comment: try a combination of [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and [chain(from itertools)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) : ```list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*A)))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them using

```
for i in range(len(A[0])):
    for j in range(len(A)):
        print(A[j][i])
```

Comment: for i in range(len(A[0])):
    for j in range(len(A)):
        print(A[j][i])

Comment: @MarianD didn't though about it sorry..

Answer (score 1):

If you can use something that’s not in the standard library, numpy is a good tool for modifying lists and matrices. You can do something like the following:

```
import numpy as np

A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]] 

print(np.asarray(A).T)
```